# How do I get a data from a Retrofit onResponse

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, callback, retrofit

I want to get an `ArrayList<ItemList>` from my Retrofit Callback and save it in as a `ArrayList` variable in my class.
In other word I need to use data from `retrofitList` even when I leave the `onResponse` method.
What is the best way to do it?
Here is my code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    retrofitList = new ArrayList<>();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://b98afcf5.ngrok.io/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    jsonPlaceHolder = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolder.class);

    Call<List<ItemList>> call = jsonPlaceHolder.getItemList();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ItemList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ItemList>> call, Response<List<ItemList>> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                return;
            }
            List<ItemList> listOfitems = response.body();
            for(ItemList itemList : listOfitems){
                retrofitList.add(new ItemList(itemList.getId(),
                        itemList.getName(),
                        itemList.getPhone(),
                        itemList.getIsLocated()));
            }
            //I WANT TO SAVE "retrofitList" INTO MY CLASS FROM HERE
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ItemList>> call, Throwable t) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: You want to save it in variable? it is already saved!

Comment: Hey Jamaldin, I want to save the list into another variable so I can read it in my class

Comment: Yes you have retrofitList and it stores your value which you have added in for loop

Comment: Why can't you access it through retrofitList since your are already populating it?

Comment: Because once I leave onResponse I lose my data and I want to store it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend serialization it will make your life easier. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685409/how-to-receive-a-json-array-result-with-retrofit2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52787794/how-to-get-gson-retrofit-to-serialize-and-map-an-array-from-a-json-response-in).
Create a method in your class that you will call from onResponse with your list. Save the list in some field variable. If you call this variable before it is filled with items from onResponse it won't have them.